# I hate Outlook Emails: Missing Border Editions '07, '10, '13

Tags: css, html-email, outlook-2007

Yes, almost everyone hates creating emails in Outlook (Android is almost as bad with Gmail and such). But, most of us are whingeing about getting rid of borders and I am whingeing about a border that does not want to work in Outlook '07, '10 & '13 (the usual suspects). Here is the code. It works everywhere...perfectly. Beautifully. Exquisitely. I have seen no one deal with a missing border. Can you help me, please...Godfather?

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="594" border="3" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: #b29d6c 3px solid;" class="deviceWidth">
```

Comment: Try giving `border: 3px solid #b29d6c;`

Comment: can you give more of the code, you may have something overwriting it elsewhere that we cannot see from this snippet. I would try removing box-sizing as support is almost non-existent, and potentially could be causing your layout issues.

Comment: <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="594" border="3" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: #b29d6c 3px solid;" class="deviceWidth">

Comment: Thanks...I looked at it for hours. 3px first...never saw that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the entirety of your code, I cannot give you any other suggestions but will provide some proof that the code I am providing (see below) should work for the Outlook version that you are experiencing issues with.

**Outlook 2007**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcurW.png

**Outlook 2011**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFoKs.png

**Outlook 2013**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bTbs.png

I have tested the code that you have provide. Here is a sample code that I put together that include your code at the very top. Notice that in all of the screen grabs above, setting your `border` properties does in fact work. There could be other issues within the entirety of your `HTML`.

### Sample Code

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                </head>
            <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="margin: 0px;outline: none;padding: 0px;width: 100%;background-color: #EFEFEF;background: #EFEFEF;">
                <div style="margin: 0px;outline: none;padding: 0px;width: 100%;background-color: #EFEFEF;background: #EFEFEF;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;text-align: center;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="min-width: 650px;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="650" valign="top" align="left" style="padding:50px;background-color: #ffffff;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;text-align:left;line-height:150px;line-height:1.5;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">


                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="3" style="border: #b29d6c 3px solid;min-width: 650px;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="650" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:50px;background-color: #ffffff;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;text-align:center;line-height:150px;line-height:1.5;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    This example sets the border styling on the table tag, not the table cell
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                        <br><br><br><br>

                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="min-width: 650px;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="650" valign="top" align="center" style="border: #b29d6c 3px solid;padding:50px;background-color: #ffffff;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;text-align:center;line-height:150px;line-height:1.5;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    Has the CSS border properties set on the table cell
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                        <br><br><br><br>

                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="min-width: 650px;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center" style="background-color:#b29d6c;padding:3px;">
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="min-width: 650px;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:50px;background-color: #ffffff;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:15px;color:#555555;text-align:center;line-height:150px;line-height:1.5;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                                This technique uses an outter table with the background color of the border and a padding set to 3 pixel to mimic the borders around the text block.
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: I actually did do the pseudo-border (600px table with a 594px table inside). Emails, designers, and coding do not mix!!!